# Erlang serial IO

Tags: serial-port, erlang, at-command

I want to talk to my modem with erlang. It is mounted as /dev/ttyUSB and perfectly understands AT-commands.

- Can I read and write from the device with the standard file module?
- How about baudrate, bytesize, parity, RTS/CTS, DSR/DTR and the like?
- Have you any experiences with tonyg-erlang-serial-1.0? (I am not too convinced of this package as it says in the readme: "This is a port program with erlang driver for serial communication,
  originally written by Johan Bevemyr in 1996 and sporadically
  maintained by Tony Garnock-Jones from 2007 onwards."
- What is the common practice for serial I/O in erlang?

Comment: I've tried `erlang-serial` (along with `gen_serial` http://blog.spearce.org/2004/02/genserial-01-released.html), but couldn't get it to work for me.

Comment: https://github.com/systra/erlang-serial   (with rebar support)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is apparently no serial communication library for erlang. I now had to dig up python again, use pyserial, spawn the python threads from erlang and communicate via stdin.

If anyone knows better, please proof me wrong. I would love to have erlang native serial I/O.

Comment: Let me know how different it is from using a port to execute a code written in another language ?

Comment: If you want to use `Erlang` and `Python` together you can take a look at http://erlport.org

Answer (score 5):

Get erlang-serial with rebar support from github.com/systra/erlang-serial. Here is a simple usage example:

```
Serial = serial:start([{speed,38400},{open,"/dev/ttya"}]),
Serial ! {send, <<"test">>},
receive
    {data,FromOtherSide} ->
        doStuff(FromOtherSide);
    Other ->
        Other
end.
```

Comment: Looks promising but I have an install error: https://github.com/tonyg/erlang-serial/issues/14 followed the instructions

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about writing to device files , then you cannot do it using the available file modules in erlang.

You will have to open a port and execute your c/C++ code.

Check if  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517393/opening-a-device-file-using-erlang)  helps.

Comment: @DownVoter : Care to comment !!