# Erlang and wavecom

Tags: erlang, serial-port

I want to create something similar to Kannel, for my wavecom GSM modem using Erlang.

I found a erlang-serial project in Github, but it seems there isn't any easy tutorial for a newbee like me.

I really need an Erlang lib that can send data to a serial port and sending AT command to my GSM modem.

Please help.

Comment: In this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976117/erlang-serial-io  The consensus seems to be that you have to use python

Comment: Look at this topic, maybe it would help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517393/opening-a-device-file-using-erlang

Comment: Yes, I read that too ... only one problem, I don't code Python ... I code in both Erlang & Java, 

Well I could use Erlang Jinterface to communicate with java-to-com-port library (http://rxtx.qbang.org) ... but to build a solution based on 2 virtual machines (JVM & Erlang runtime) would make my solution too difficult to deploy, same goes if I use Python.

I prefer using windows or linux shared library (*.dll or *.so), because those are natively delivered as part of the OS where I would like my solution to be deployed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**erlang-serial** has pretty easy example in [terminal.erl](https://github.com/tonyg/erlang-serial/blob/master/src/terminal.erl), basically you start the connection:

```
SerialPort = serial:start([{speed,Speed},{open,?DEVICE}]),
serial_listener()
```

Where **?DEVICE** is path to linux device in **/dev** and **serial_listener** is a receive-loop like this:

```
serial_listner() ->
receive
{data, Bytes} ->
    %% Do something with bytes
    serial_listner()
end.
```

And to send data you just send message to that process:

```
SerialPort ! {send, Bytes}
```

That's it!